# why my swap is not working in cyclic sort?

Tags: java, swap

```
     int temp=arr[i];
     arr[i]=arr[arr[i]-1];
     arr[arr[i]-1]=temp;
```

This Swap part of the code is not working correctly. i have written same swap code for other sorting algorithms, but I am facing issue with this. Also anyone can please give me clarity on pass by value of java.

Comment: you are stuck in a inifinite loop. Debug it and you will see that.

Comment: For future reference "I am facing issue with this" isn't going to help. At least tell us _what_ issue you're facing.

Comment: There are several problems with the code. I'm tempted to answer, and point out each problem.  But, I believe you will learn more if you run the code with a debugger, and see what changes step-by-step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr[i]=arr[arr[i]-1];
arr[arr[i]-1]=temp;
```

This doesn't work as a swap because `arr[i]` changes on the first line, so it points to a different index.

Instead, you probably want

```
arr[i] = arr[temp - 1];
arr[temp - 1] = temp;
```

...since you already have `arr[i]` stored in a convenient variable.